# Remove Char after last special char

Tags: c#, char

Hi I have a string maybe like this

```
string str="user1,user2,user3,user4,user5,user6";
```

I want remove all of string at last `,` then the str became `user6`.
How can I do it use c#

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look at LastIndexOf and Substring...

Comment: `str.Split(',').Last()`?

Comment: Use a different delimiter or use quoting characters around each token like `"user1","user2",...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
string newStr = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(",") + 1));
```

or add `using System.Linq;` and use:

```
string newStr = str.Split(',').Last();
```

Comment: Given the nature of the question you might wanna mention he needs a "using System.Linq;"

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using Linq as follows.

```
string Result
    = str.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
```